# ¿Cómo encontrar error de "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING" en Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Agradecería si pueden ayudarme con una petición con retrofit 2. No sé cómo encontrar el error. Adjunto dos imágenes con la respuesta de Android y Postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Pero con POSTMAN si realizo la petición, me devuelve el JSON correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido! Puedes sustituir las imagenes por texto?

Comment: @Marc Lemien rechacé tu [sugerencia de edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27230). Me parece que dejaste muchas cosas en el tintero, como muestra la ulterior revisión de Mariano. Tenlo en cuenta para futuras sugerencias --si quieres, claro :)

Comment: Añade el código donde creas el `JSON`, y lo retornas. A primera vista está claro que tu `JSON` no tiene como primer carácter `{` sino algo que lo reconoce como cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Librerías como `Retrofit` o `Gson` pueden provocar este error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

La causa, es que no es un objeto lo que intentas leer ya que no tiene como contenedor `{` al inicio. Veo que agregas la respuesta con Postman, pero revisa tu `LogCat`, al tratar de realizar la petición en la aplicación estas obteniendo un

> "Error 400 - Bad Request"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por lo tanto lo que responde al realizar la petición en tu aplicación en realidad no es un objeto JSON.**

Asegura que los valores que envías al realizar la petición sean correctos!

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi caso tenia un error en la url de la petición, no deberia ir el "/" porque era de mas, deben tener mucho cuidado al declarar una constante como por ejemplo:

```
val URL_GLOBAL = "https://ejemplo.ws/admin/"
```

deberia ser asi:

```
val URL_GLOBAL = "https://ejemplo.ws/admin"
```